# Basic set of libraries in chroot (fedora linux)

Tags: linux, gcc, fedora, glibc

I'm running an old version of my linux distro (fedora, but this is not very relevant) and for reasons which are completely irrelevant I'm not in a position to update it. However I do need a newer version of gcc and some other libraries than those supplied by my old distro.

I could compile a newer gcc and all the other libraries of course but I thought the simplest way would be to install a minimal set of packages from the latest distro version to a directory and then just chroot there. This way I'd take advantage of the binary packages present in the newest distro and all the infrastructure around it (like dependency installation, etc.) and I wouldn't need to compile everything from source.

My question is this: if I only would like to be able to compile with the most recent gcc and run those programs, what is the minimal set of packages I need? Since we are talking about fedora, what is the minimal set of rpms (beyond glibc and gcc)? Note that I don't need any X environment, networking, or anything like that, only the most basic terminal tools.

Comment: the basic set of libraries you need is no different from within a chrooted environment. Your question is a bit ambiguous - do you want to know the minimal set of libraries or do you want to know how to setup a chrooted environment?

Comment: I'd like to know the minimal set of packages which make a chroot operational.

Answer (score 0):

The minimal set varies depending on your user needs and what you're linking with. What I do when making a chroot environment is have a look at the distro I want to chroot and see if they have a base rpm/deb package that kickstarts everything. Then I install that in the chroot. From there I add libraries and applications as needed.

For an example where I create a chroot for RHEL on Arch see http://www.zenskg.net/wordpress/?p=267